# Python3 While Loop jumping to else statement

Tags: python, input

Im in my first couple of weeks of programming. I am trying to make a function that asks for a users input, checks whether or not that input is alphabetic, if it is alphabetic then i want to break the while loop.

If I run the script and enter the correct types in the input it breaks and works fine. If I intentionally put a number in the input field it doesn't break out of the loop when I reenter the correct type.

any ideas on what im doing wrong?

```
def wallType():
    wall_type = input("What type of wall was the route on?  ")
    while wall_type:
        #if there is text in the input,instead of an alphanumeric, then tell them they must put in a number.
        if str.isalpha(wall_type):
            return wall_type
        else:
            print("You entered a number, you must enter a word. Try again.  ")
            wallType()
```

Comment: When you recursively call `wallType()` after an incorrect entry, the inner instance of the function will presumably return a valid value - but the outer, original instance then completely ignores that value, and is still stuck in its own while loop.

Comment: @jasonharper Do you have any recommendations on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a `while True` loop. When input received is alphabetic, use `break` to break out of `while` loop. Else loop again to ask for input.

```
def wallType():
    while True:
        wall_type = input("What type of wall was the route on?  ")

        # string is alphabetic, break out of loop
        if str.isalpha(wall_type):
            break
        else:
            print("Please reenter an alphabetic word. Try again.  ")
```